# ASP.NET: ImageButton not in the middle

Tags: asp.net, css

I worked over 1 hour on a 1-pixel-thing, here is the code:

```
                <div id="Zeitraum" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; padding:5px;">
                Zeitraum:
                <asp:DropDownList  ID="ddlZeit" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10 Tage" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="30 Tage" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="60 Tage" Value="60"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Text="Alle" Value="100"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSend" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/NavForward.png" Width="15px" Height="15px" style="" />
            </div>
```

Here is the image:
http://s2.imgimg.de/uploads/Capture04273f43PNG.png

The `ImageButton` is not in the middle like the text and the `DropDownList`. Why?
I tried margin and padding and many many other things, but nothing helped.

Comment: what browser did you take your image from? Have you tried others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the button lower by setting following style:
`<asp:ImageButton ID="imgSend" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/NavForward.png" Width="15px" Height="15px" style="position: relative; top: 2px" />`

Answer (score 1):

put table in div as like this, I have tested it my machine, it is looking fine now...

```
<div id="Zeitraum" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; padding: 5px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Zeitraum:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlZeit" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10 Tage" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="30 Tage" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="60 Tage" Value="60"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Text="Alle" Value="100"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSend" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/NavForward.png"
                    Width="15px" Height="15px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: good thing, but Majkel was as good as you and I try to avoid every table I can

Answer (score 0):

Changing margin or padding won't help you, as it's an inline html element and you'll just set margin/padding against the containing box for the whole row.  Look at `vertical-align` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `vertical-align` CSS property on the *DropDownList*, not the ImageButton. Unfortunately this property seems to give wildly different results across browsers and browser versions.

Comment: Try the vert-align overall, nothing appears